# LINQ & SQL Server : order by from starting row

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, partial-ordering, sql-order-by

I have a table which has three columns: `username`, `followerCount` and `CreateDate`.

There are around 110000 users in the table and I am trying to show users ordered by `followerCount`. I do as follows:

```
select top 50 * 
from Users 
where followerCount <= @followerCount
order by followerCount desc, createDate desc
```

So for second page I pass last `followerCount` from first page and I receive next page and so on.

But there are some users in the table that they have same follower count. For example there are 250 users has 5000 followers. So when I do paging, I cannot get next page correctly because there are more users with 5000 followers.

For example I am on page 9 and last user has 5001 followers, I pass 5001 to stored procedure and I get 50 users who has 5000 users. But there are 200 users more and when I pass this time 5000 (last number from prev paging) again to my stored procedure it will skip all the rest and bring me users with 4xxx followers.

How can I achieve to bring correct users who has same amount of followers?

Correction: I am using Entity Framework for this purpose, I posted SQL statement for easy understanding.

Comment: A single parameter @followerCount is not enough to define what you want. If you are using EF6.1.2+ with SQL-Server 2012, you can add the SKIP and TAKE more efficiently with `OFFSET FETCH` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep track of what page # you are on, then you can use Skip and Take to do your paging for you:

```
var page=9; //Set to whatever page you want
var pageSize=50;
var results=db.Users
  .OrderByDescending(u=>u.followerCount)
  .ThenByDescending(u=>u.createDate)
  .Skip((page-1)*pageSize)
  .Take(pageSize);
```

If you need your stored procedure to do the paging for you, then you need to read up on how [ROW_NUMBER OVER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.90).aspx) works for older versions of SQL Server (pre-2012) or [OFFSET FETCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) for newer ones.